# Android Multiple Nested DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-support-library

I have a scenario where I show a `DialogFragment` (using `getSupportFragmentManager()`) that shows a list of values and an "Add" button. If the user clicks the add button, I display another `DialogFragment` (using `getChildFragmentManager()` that consists of an `EditText` and `Button`. When the user clicks the new `Button` if the value passes validation, I add it to the list. If it doesn't pass validation, I show another `DialogFragment` that displays an error message, and an "OK" button. I would like it that when the "OK" button is pressed, the user will still see the `DialogFragment` with the `EditText` and `Button` so that they could look over the bad value and possibly change it. However, when the "OK" button is pressed in the error message `DialogFragment`, the dialog is dismissed, and only the original `DialogFragment` (the one with the list of values) is displayed.

How would I keep the second `DialogFragment` still displayed after the third one is dismissed?

**EDIT:** Here are some code snippets:

```
//clicking this button shows the first ("outer") fragment
findViewById(R.id.voicemail_notifications_email_addresses).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddressListDialog.newInstance( 
                   line, AddressListDialog.VOICEMAIL_NOTIFICATIONS_EMAIL)
                  .show(((FragmentActivity)getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }

});

public static class AddressListDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public AddressListDialog() {}

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.vm_address_list_dialog, null);
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.voicemail_notifications_address_list);
        final AddressAdapter adapter = new AddressAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        v.findViewById(R.id.voicemail_add_address_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //first child fragment
                AddAddressDialog.newInstance(getType()).setAdapter(adapter)
                                .show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            }

        });

        Dialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(titleRes)
                .setView(v)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.global_dialog_pos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .create();
        return d;
    }

    private class AddressAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        .
        .
        .
        public boolean add(LineVoicemailInfo.VmContact contact) {
            if(addresses.size() >= 3) {
                return false;
            }
            else if(!contact.isValid(isEmailType())) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                addresses.add(contact);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        }

public static class AddAddressDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private AddressAdapter adapter;

    public AddAddressDialog() {}

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener onPosClick = null;

        final View v;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.voicemail_add_email_address, null);
        onPosClick = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                        
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                LineVoicemailInfo.VmContact contact = new LineVoicemailInfo.VmContact(((EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.voicemail_add_email_address)).getText().toString());
                if(!adapter.add(contact)) {
                    //second child fragment
                    BadAddressDialog.newInstance("Not a valid address")
                                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog");
                }
            }
        };


        Dialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Add Address")
                .setView(v)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.voicemail_addresses_add, onPosClick)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.global_dialog_neg, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                })
                .create();
        setCancelable(false);
        return d;
    }
}

public static class BadAddressDialog extends DialogFragment {           
        public BadAddressDialog() {}

        public static BadAddressDialog newInstance(String message) {
            BadAddressDialog frag = new BadAddressDialog();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("message", message);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
            String message = getArguments().getString("message");

            Dialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Error adding address")
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.global_dialog_pos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
            setCancelable(false);
            return d;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mind to show related code?

Comment: I suppose the problem can be that you use standard `show` method for displaying dialogs. According to Android sources, this method does not add fragment to backstack, so then the top-most dialog is dismissed, the middle is dismissed as well. You should begin trasaction on your own before calling `show` and add the transaction to backstack (call `addToBackStack`). An example is shown on [DialogFragment documentation page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Comment: @Stan that worked! Thanks so much. Do you want to put that as an answer so I can give it to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that you use standard `show` method for displaying dialogs. According to Android sources, this method does not add fragment to backstack, so then the top-most dialog is dismissed, the middle is dismissed as well.

You should begin trasaction on your own before calling `show` and add the transaction to backstack (call `addToBackStack`). An example is shown on [DialogFragment documentation page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).